# Proving a continuity of functions in C[0,1]

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a<b$ be real numbers, and $K:[a,b]\times[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. For each $x \in C[a,b]$, define $$(F(x))(t)=\int_{[a,b]}K(t,s)x(s)\ ds\ \ \ \ \text{for all}\ \ t\in[a,b].$$ \
Need to show: $F:C[0,1] \rightarrow C[0,1]$ is continuous with respect to $d_{\infty}$.

Let $\epsilon>0$, $t \in [0,1]$, and $x(t) \in [0,1]$. Since $K$ is continuous on a compact interval, there exists $M>0 $ such that $|K(t,s)|\leq M$ for any $(t,s) \in [a,b]\times [a,b]$. Now, let $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{M(b-a)}$, clearly $\delta>0$. Let $x'(t) \in C[0,1]$ be such that $d_\infty(x(t),x'(t))<\delta.$ Then, \begin{align*}
    d_{\infty}(F(x(t)),F(x'(t)))&=\max_{t \in [a,b]}\left|\int_{[a,b]}K(t,s)x(s)-K(t,s)x'(s)\ \ ds\right|\\
    &\leq \max_{t \in [a,b]}\int_{[a,b]}|K(t,s)(x(s)-x'(s))|\ ds\\
    &=\max_{t \in [a,b]}\int_{[a,b]}|K(t,s)|\ |(x(s)-x'(s))|\ ds\\
    & \leq \max_{t \in [a,b]}M\int_{[a,b]}|(x(s)-x'(s))|
\end{align*}

My problem is with bounding $|(x(s)-x'(s))|$, i dont see that is less than my chosen delta, so I would really to see other ideas about this.

Thank you.

Comment: is $d_{\infty}(x,y) = sup\{ |x(t) - y(t)| : t \in [a,b] \}$ ?

Comment: You know that $|x(t)| \le \|x\|_\infty$ for all $t$. Hence $\le M \|x-x'\|_\infty$, and so Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: I agree but when choosing delta, it was chosen for a specific point in $[a,b]$ and we dont know if the $s$ close to $t$?